# What kind of wiring is this?

Tags: electrical, wiring, knob-and-tube

Single conductor in a very rigid rubbery or tar like jacket.  Almost like a knob and tube with an outer jacket that is like a continuous tube.  This stuff is long-ago decommissioned but I'm just curious what it is.  I have seen deco'd "regular" k&T in other places in the house but never saw anything like this before.   I tried to read the writing stamped in it but it's illegible.

[image]
[image]

Update: Here are thre more small pieces of this stuff that I discovered later. (And again, this stuff is all long ago decommissioned).

From these smaller pieces it looks to me like this was an advancement on K&T where "long tubes" could be used in relatively free spaces and directions.  That's a guess.   Like crafting your own single-conductor MC.

[image]

Comment: Not K&T as it has no knobs or tubes unless those are hidden.  Looks like an early variety of insulated wire to me.

Comment: So, later than k&t but before metal?

Comment: Possibly.  There were a lot of one-off solutions in the early days of electrical wiring.  I'm hoping that some old-timer will chime in here with a more definitive answer.

Comment: The heavy insulation suggests that one end saw outdoor use of some sort. Where is this located? Could it have been former external lighting perhaps?

Comment: Not an oldtimer (I hope!) but I’d say that’s knob and tube with an additional sheath where the wires were crossing or ran the risk of bumping into each other.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I've exposed a few more bits of it since taking those pictures, and it looks like you are on the right track.  It looks like that is armor applied on site to a single conductor.  You could think of it as early self-installed armor, or as a "long tube".   That's just my guess from what I'm seeing in the small amount I've exposed.

Comment: That looks like some asphalt covered wiring if memory serves it was used in the 20’s and 30’s it was similar to K&T as it was individually run but there was an inner insulation and an outter asphalt coating, I have seen it used with K&T boxes (ceramic insulators) but the wires passed through framing members after this there was a cloth wrapped. I don’t think the asphalt covering would fit through a tube type insulator.

Comment: @EdBeal I think you are right.  See my added photo and comment.  These definitely would not go through tubes, they are about the same size as tubes but slightly flexible and it seems like they extend "knob and tube" to simply "lots of long tubes" that don't need the support of knobs or framing.

Comment: That photo shows the K&T in the background, I don’t know the exact dates this was it was in use but homes in the 20-30’s is where I remember it , cloth coated was in by the 40’s it was the first step to NM wiring we know today. Your home looks somewhat common as far as old homes, K&T , asphalt, BX, possibly cloth to the right of thr Romex and well the Romex.  This was used late in the life of K&T when it was really on its way out having the heavy insulation you did not need the insulators but at the boxes they were still needed (this may be the original requirement for 1/4” inside the box)?

Comment: If there was any EMT or repurposed gas pipes as conduit, the answer would be... *all of them*.

Comment: @EdBeal thank you and yes, quite a *history of wiring* in two square feet.  I can't easily photograph where that yellow NM goes from and to but I am in complete awe of the electricians who did it.  Fishing magic.    The thing to the right of the Romex is 1980s "cable guy" coax.  Also somewhat impressive as their habit was to run everything on the surface.

Comment: @Mazura ha! Yes, there is a little EMT in the basement, that I added a few years ago so we can add that to the inventory.  And lots of disused gas pipes in the walls (the house was lit by gas for a decade or more) but none of them repurposed for wiring.  For the highly discerning in addition to the BX you see there was also some more recent MC that I ripped out before I took this photo.

Comment: @EdBeal sounds like your comments are the makings of an answer

Answer (score 2):

This is knob-and-tube era in-wall wiring.  The inner portion is what runs between the knobs and through the tubes, and when it runs vertically, it gets sheathed in the outer jacket.  It's not really an "advancement" of K&T, just the unseen part used inside walls or wherever the actual knobs and tubes weren't feasible.